# Delphi Android blackscreen after some builds

Tags: android, delphi, build, apk

The applications (apk) gives a black screen after some time. 
It started with a local database inside the application and at first I thought I was at fault. So I remade the project and it went well.

But the next day it gives a black screen on defining the activeTab on a TabControl. Searched some bit for causes but couldn't find any and again remade it and it went good.

Next day again.....But then with a Ini file implementation.

I have tried to clean and build it, and tried a new project and imported the classes to the new project. But no luck.

Is the android phone not strong enough? Or is it some thing wrong with 10.1 Berlin mobile add-on? Or am I in the wrong. enlightenment needed, please.

Answer (score 0):

their is no answer to your problem, because it's can be this or that. the best answer is that you must add a max on log everywhere in you code to figure what goes wrong.

for exemple in every procedure add

```
procedure xxx;
begin
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  ALLog('xxx', 'Start', TalLogType.verbose);
{$ENDIF}      
....
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  ALLog('xxx', 'End', TalLogType.verbose);
{$ENDIF}      
end;
```

and after in Android device monitor you will easily figure out with procedure make the crash. i guess it's not inside the main thread UI you have the error else you will receive a message and not app that close